# $watch function on filter in angularJS

Tags: angularjs-filter

I am having the {{ content | lang }} expression in my .html file to update the text on browser based on lang filter. But it is not updating the page when I changed the language.

When I tried with {{ (content | lang) || content }}  expression it works as expected.

I am not sure what is the difference in both of these.

is there anyone facing the same issue?

I am using angular 1.4.2 version.

Comment: Because your `lang` filter returns null, it falls to the default value provided at the right of your OR statement. Don't debug any `$watch`, debug your filter. By the way, I don't think `lang` is part from Angular. You should give another look into the Localization tutorial you followed that made you choose this Localization tool.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this filter is effective if placed in parenthesis and combined with other expressions. A filter is supposed to work. Thus, I think it is up to the filter to return a default value.

Comment: lang is custom filter that I created.

Comment: I debug the filter and filter returns the right output but it does not update the page.